# Use QUERY with PIVOT and need sum blank amount to be zero

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[image] [image]

The shared sheet includes why I need to fill zero just to make the Radar chart look nicer

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rP-xmEsL11SyQg-2f8VGlyyZ33KbnWJogdqs_Di1Ns/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY({A:C},
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2", 1)*1, QUERY({A:C},
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  pivot Col2", 1)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It actually has a solution for this. Amazing formula, to combine 2 arrays and use `IF` to return which array to display. Thanks a lot.